# check and replace alphanumeric pattern using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a requirement where the input value needs to be checked so that it follows a fixed pattern, if not, fix it to the pattern using `sed`.

Final output ONLY needs to be in this pattern `env00XX` where XX is from 01 to 49

some inputs I might expect ENV00XX, Env00XX, env1 env2 ... env9, or any other criteria needs to be reset to env0001 to env0049 (lowercase env and 4 digits upto 49)

I have tried many ways closest are 
`sed -r ":r;s/\b[0-9]{1,3}\b/0&/g;tr"`  gives me 3 to 0003 and 23 to 0023

also `echo ENV001 | sed 'y/ENV/env/' | sed -e 's/00*//g'` gives me from ENV001 to env1

But I cannot go further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`echo 'EnV009' | sed 's/env\([0-9]\{1,\}\)/env000\1/I;s/0*\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1/'`

Explanation: The first sed expression `s/\(env\)\([0-9]\{1,\}\)/env000\2/I` searches case-insensitively for "env" followed by at least one digit. It then replaces the matched text with "env", followed by three zeros, followed by the matched digit pattern (one or more digits).

**EnV009 becomes env000009**

The second sed expression `s/0*\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1/` takes the output of the first, and slices off the extra zeros before the last four digits.

**env000009 becomes env0009**